# Long QGIS project loading time due to QgsPostgresProvider SQL calls

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql

QGIS 3.22.8 LTR.

**Setup**

I have a QGIS project file which contains around 100 PostGIS layers, hosted in Azure PostgreSQL (similar to AWS RDS). All layers were added via 'Add PostGIS Layers...' tool (not DB manager, although my tests show this info is irrelevant). Other settings on every layer: `estimatedmetadata=true` and `checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='0'`, primary key and spatial index exist too.

**Issue**

The issue is the project file takes around 2-3 minutes to load. This is far too long for roll out to general users within my organisation.

**Investigation**

Using the SQL Query logger on the newer QGIS 3.28.1, I've been able to view the SQL queries being run on project load. What I'm seeing is that the bulk of loading time is due to `QgsPostgresProvider` SQL calls to the PostgreSQL database for each column on each table loaded. Such provider categories (as found in: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp ) are:

- `QgsPostgresProvider::loadFields`
- `QgsPostgresProvider::QgsPostgresProvider`
- `QgsPostgresProvider::getGeometryDetails`
- `QgsPostgresProvider::hasSufficientPermsAndCapabilities`
- `QgsPostgresProvider::determinePrimaryKey`
- `QgsPostgresProvider::parseDomainCheckConstraint`
- `QgsPostgresProvider::enumValues`

The latter 2 take up the bulk of the **11,742 line** SQL query log, appearing almost 400 times each. Such examples of these in the .json output look like:

```
 {
    "Initiator": "QgsPostgresProvider",
    "Location": "src\\providers\\postgres\\qgspostgresprovider.cpp:2160 (QgsPostgresProvider::enumValues)",
    "Provider": "postgres",
    "Row count": "1",
    "SQL": "SELECT typtype FROM pg_type WHERE typname='varchar'",
    "Started at": "2022-12-19T12:26:42.466",
    "Total time (ms)": "21",
    "URI": "dbname='gis_db' host=servername.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 user='reader' password='xxxx'"
  },
  {
    "Initiator": "QgsPostgresProvider",
    "Location": "src\\providers\\postgres\\qgspostgresprovider.cpp:2211 (QgsPostgresProvider::parseDomainCheckConstraint)",
    "Provider": "postgres",
    "Row count": "1",
    "SQL": "SELECT domain_name, domain_schema FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='areas_benefiting_from_flood_defences_subdiv' AND column_name='layer'",
    "Started at": "2022-12-19T12:26:42.487",
    "Total time (ms)": "24",
    "URI": "dbname='gis_db' host=servername.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 user='reader' password='xxxx'"
  },
```

Any ideas to why these queries are requried? Often on each column per table? Seems excessive.

**UPDATE**

Interestingly, I've added up all the `"Total time (ms)": "n"` values, and it *only* totals 22 seconds. This means the query executions aren't the primary cause of the project load slowdown. The 'Project Load' debugging tool in QGIS shows 95 seconds to read all map layers. This is much closer to the observed wait I manually timed when opening the project file. We can see here the 'Create postgres provider' is the main culprit. Any solutions or ideas to speed up this process?

[image: QGIS project load debugger]

Comment: To pinpoint the source of the issue, you can try with a local copy of the DB as establishing many connections over the network may be fairly slow.

Comment: @JGH network is definitely a factor here, because if I open the QGIS file from a VM that is 'closer' to our Azure gateway, the project load takes 1.5 mins instead of 2-3 mins. I still maintain that there are some excessive metadata and 'Create postgres provider' calls being made to PostgreSQL by QGIS.